# AngularJS, controller error after uglify: Unknown provider: aProvider <- a

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

The following code snippet creates some mock data that is used in a template. It works before uglification but after I get the "Unknown provider: aProvider <- a" error.

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('ReportListController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

    $scope.reports = mockData();

    function mockData() {
        var reports = [];
        for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            reports.push({ ...mock json data... });
        }

        return reports;
    }
}]);
```

I've read the info on the link provided in the error message ([link](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr?p0=aProvider%20%3C-%20a)) and on various similar Stack Overflow questions (that all seemed to be resolved) but I can't see where my code differs from the instructions.

Comment: Are you sure this is the controller that is giving the error? Is the controller ever called anywhere else in the code? I only ever got that error because I didn't protect everything from minification (which it looks as if this controller is).

Comment: @MatthewGreen thank you for the reply. I'm positive, if I comment everything inside this specific controller the error goes away.

Answer (score 1):

Its worked for me - Im using grunt

```
uglify: {
options: {
  mangle: false
}
```

Read about `ng-annotate`